# ng-grid does not refresh with $resource service

Tags: ng-grid, angularjs-resource

ng-grid is not updating my list.

I am trying to create a object in one view and on creating I redirect my page to list view where i want to see all my added objects. I am able to create a new object through api call and on success I call the view which should ideally show list of all objects, however I dont see the latest added object (On refresh I do see the same object)

Save function call in my create view:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    SERVICE.$save();
    $location.path('listview');
}
```

ListViewCtrl has and `init()` function which sets the ng grid option

```
SERVICE.query().
    $promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.ngGridOptionVariable = data;
        });
```

I dont see the new data that is being added

Any clue how to handle this issue?

Comment: Is your code making the request to the service end-point after pointing them to the new path?

Comment: Yes, it is talking to my backend. In listPage I call the service which  return me the list of objects. On save I re direct my view to list page. So I dont see the data there, however when I refresh it does show me the data.

Comment: Isn't that due to the asynchronous nature of your first request `$save` ? You should only call `$location.path('listview')` after `$save` has returned a success callback.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out, I should call next view on success :) Thanks